# change child's attr if parent is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using lightbox and hideseek plugins in my project and want to add interactions between them (one must follow the rules of another).

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li>
  <p>I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.</p>
  <a href="photos/01.jpg" alt ='Hay Bales' data-lightbox="image" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
    <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
  </a>
</li>
```

When hideseek sets `<li>` to `<li style="display: none;">` I want absolutely all children to inherit this display property but lightbox still see the image within this hidden `li` element.

So I need a js script that will change attribute of the link so that image will not show up. I came up with this code:

```
$(li).is(":hidden") {
  var index = 1;
  var child = this.childNodes[index];
  child.setAttribute("data-lightbox", "none");
}

$(li).not(":hidden") {
  var index = 1;
  var child = this.childNodes[index];
  child.setAttribute("data-lightbox", "image");
}
```

but both of them do not work. First one should hide element by changing attr and second one should set it back since the parent is visible again.

Which way would be best to write it out?

Comment: Doesn't lightbox show and hide whatever it's instantiated on? Why use 2 similar plugins?

Comment: I think the key point here is that the images that appear in the lightbox are not children of the list, they in fact are inserted into a div at the bottom of the page `#lightbox`, then `.lb-container` or some such thing. Can you supply a description of desired outcome?

Comment: Although I have no idea why, I have answered on the how to remove and add the `data-lightbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `removeData()` to remove the value then `removeAttr()` to remove the actual attribute. Add it back with `attr()`. I added a button that toggles these methods which shows that data-lightbox is removed when you see the red border disappear. Note that I have added  multiple anchors and used nothing other than `$('a')` to collect all of the links. `each()`, `children()` etc. was not needed.

**details are commented in  Demo**

### Demo

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {

  //Check to see if data-lightbox attribute exists
  if (typeof $("a").data('lightbox') !== 'undefined') {

    /* If it does then first remove the value
    || with removeData() then use removeAttr()
    || to actually remove the attribute itself
    */
    $('a').removeData('lightbox').removeAttr('data-lightbox');

  } else {

    /* Otherwise add the data-lightbox attribute
    || along with the value of image
    */
    $('a').attr('data-lightbox', 'image')
  }
});
```

```css
[data-lightbox] {
  border: 3px solid red
}
```

```html
<li>
  <p>I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.</p>
  <a href="photos/01.jpg" alt='Hay Bales' data-lightbox="image" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
    <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
  </a>
</li>
<a href="photos/01.jpg" alt='Hay Bales' data-lightbox="image" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
  <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
</a>
<a href="photos/01.jpg" alt='Hay Bales' data-lightbox="image" data-title="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
  <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
</a>
<button>On/Off</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things here. Both the of jQuery `is` and `not` functions return a boolean value. They cannot be used the what that you have them here. Your selectors need quotes. Finally to do what you are Toto do I would create a function that loops through the li elements, evaluates the display attributes and then sets the “data-lightbox” attribute accordingly.

```
function hideSeek(){
    var lis = $(‘li’);  // collection of the li elements

   // iterate through lis
    lis.forEach( function(elem) {

        /* 
            Ternary checks if the li has a attribute 
            of display none if so find the a and set 
            its data-light box to none else set it to 
            image.
         */
        $(elem).attr(‘display’) === ‘none’  ?  $(elem).find(‘a’).attr(‘data-lightbox’, ‘none’) : $(elem).find(‘a’).attr(‘data-lightbox’, ‘image’);
    });

}

$(‘button’).on(‘click’, hideSeek );
```